# How were the P-256 parameters chosen?

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

In [NIST FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf) (page 90), it is said that $c$ is the output of SHA-1 on a seed that was chosen randomly. Then the parameter $b$ of the EC is chosen, according to the formula: $$b^2 \times c \equiv -27 \pmod p$$ Why choose $b$ this way? Why, as an example, couldn't $b = c$?

Answer (score 4):

The algorithm for generating EC curve is in appendix D.5 of NIST FIPS 186-4, and the verification algorithm is in D.6. They are taken from ANSI X9.62, which justified the rationale as the following:

> In order to verify that a given elliptic curve was indeed generated at
>   random, the defining parameters of the elliptic curve are defined to
>   be outputs of the hash function SHA-1 (as specified in ANSI X9.30 Part
>   2 [4]). The input (SEED) to SHA-1 then serves as proof (under the
>   assumption that SHA-1 cannot be inverted) that the parameters were
>   indeed generated at random.

The curve generation algorithm requires $a,b$ to satisfy $b^2\cdot c \equiv a^3 \bmod p$, and it is not necessary that $a$ and $b$ be chosen at
random. In the case of NIST Prime curves, they all use fixed $a=-3$, so $b^2\cdot c \equiv -27 \bmod p$.

As to the question why $b$ cannot equal to $c$, note if $a$ is not fixed then it is actually valid to choose $a=b=c$. But  $a=-3$ is chosen by NIST, so this is not possible because the seed does not hash to $-3$.

Comment: Thank you! Can you kindly elaborate where the condition came from? Its not identical to the requirement for the discriminant #0, that is, for a certain values of random c (maybe not this one specifically), the discriminant could be zero, isn't it?

Comment: No this is not the same. That requires $4a^3+27b^2\ne 0$. In fact in NIST FIPS 186-4 D.5, step 8, it checks $4c+27\ne 0 \bmod p$, to ensure the discriminant is not 0 if $(a,b)$ is chosen by the formula $b^2\cdot c \equiv a^3$. As to where this $b^2\cdot c \equiv a^3$ formula comes from, I am not sure because it is not documented anywhere.