# How to determine secp256r1 or secp256k1 is used on the web sites

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptanalysis

I'm pretty new at Cryptography (and at Cryptanalysis), but I went to the website [Elliptic](https://www.elliptic.co/) to try to discover the elliptic curve they use, and I found they use ECDP 256. So, by SEC2 I discovered they do use either secp256r1 or secp256k1. How can I know which one they do use? I do also need to find the base point they are using. Where can I find that? Thanks.

Comment: Note that I've removed a few comments. That's just common practice if they are no longer needed, in case you are wondering. This message should self-destruct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the all information on the site that provides you can find the answer very fast.

> X9.62 ECDSA Signature with SHA-256

X9.62 : Public Key Cryptography for the Financial Services Industry: The Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Standard (ECDSA)"

So, it is the NIST curve and NIST uses the $r$ [versions](https://www.secg.org/SEC2-Ver-1.0.pdf#page=12) like secp256r1.

---

A must-read question on our site

- [Should we trust the NIST-recommended ECC parameters?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/10263/18298)